# Unable to require redis from Rails but works on console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis

I'm using Rails 2.3.3 with Redis gem v=2.2.2. I have a weird problem where Rails throws an error saying its unable to require the redis gem (no such file to load - redis Missing source file) but I'm able to work with redis on the rails console (on the same server).

I created an initializer that does this

```
require 'redis' # throws error here
REDIS_API = Redis.new(:host => '127.0.0.1', :port => '6379', :password => 'xxxxxx')
put REDIS_API.inspect
```

This works fine on the console and on the local server(OS X) and my staging server (Ubuntu) but fails to require 'redis' in production (Ubuntu)

My gemlist shows the gem as well.

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (2.3.3)
actionpack (2.3.3)
activerecord (2.3.3)
activeresource (2.3.3)
activesupport (3.1.3, 2.3.3)
bundler (1.0.21)
chronic (0.6.6)
daemon_controller (0.2.6)
daemons (1.1.5)
eventfulapi (2.2.1)
fastthread (1.0.7)
geokit (1.6.0)
geokit-rails (1.1.4)
highline (1.6.9)
i18n (0.6.0)
mime-types (1.17.2)
multi_json (1.0.4)
mysql2 (0.3.11)
nokogiri (1.5.0)
passenger (3.0.11)
pg (0.12.0)
rack (1.0.1)
rails (2.3.3)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rake-compiler (0.7.9)
redis (2.2.2)
right_aws (3.0.0)
right_http_connection (1.3.0)
rspec (1.2.8)
rubygems-update (1.5.3)
whenever (0.7.2)
```

I'm using rvm with Ruby-1.8.7-p352. Any idea what I could be missing. I;m completely clueless at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Did you added gem name in environment.rb file `config.gem 'redis'`

Comment: Please add the stacktrace here and try this "config.gem 'redis', :path => 'gem_path'".